# Building tests with mocha for async code (request)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to create unit tests with Mocha and Chai on Node.JS. Here is a simplified version of the function to test:

```
router.cheerioParse = function(url, debugMode, db, theme, outCollection, _callback2) {
    var nberror = 0;
    var localCount = 0;
    console.log("\nstarting parsing now :  " + theme);
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        //a lot of postprocessing here that returns 
        //true when everything goes well)
    });
}
```

Here is the test I am trying to write:

```
describe('test', function(){
    it('should find documents', function(){
        assert(  true ==webscraping.cheerioParse("http://mytest.com,   null, null, null ,null,null ));
    });
})
```

How can the `request` function return true to have it passed to the test? I have tried to use promises but it didn't work either. In this case should I put the return statement in the `then` callback? What is the best approach?

Comment: Mocha supports both [Async API](http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) and [Promises](http://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises)

Answer (score 0):

You should mock `request` function. You could use e.g. `sinon` stubs for this (they provide `returns` function for defining returning value).

In general - the idea of unit tests is to separate particular function (unit of test) and stub every other dependency, as you should do with `request` :)

To do so, you have to overwrite original `request` object, e.g. :

```
before(function() {
  var stub = sinon.stub(someObjectThatHasRequestMethod, 'request').returns(true);
});
```

And after running tests you should unstub this object for future tests like that:

```
after(function() {
  stub.restore();
});
```

And that's all :) You could use both `afterEach/after` or `beforeEach/before` - choose the one that suits you better.

One more note - because your code is asynchronous, it is possible that your solution might need more sophisticated way of testing. You could provide whole `request` mock function and call `done()` callback when returning value like this:

```
it('should find documents', function(done) {
  var requestStub = sinon.stub(someObjectThatHasRequestMethod, 'request',
    function(url, function (error, response, body) {
      done();
      return true;
  }
  assert(true === webscraping.cheerioParse("http://mytest.com,   null, null, null ,null,null ));
  requestStub.restore();
});
```

You could find more info here:

[Mocha - asynchronous code testing](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code)